# Dynamic value occurrence changing every time in response

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to capture below value
FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251659"

and i  used below expression
FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"(.*?)"

But there is lot of other values with these boundaries and 3659174697251659 value occurrence changing in response every time when replay script in jmeter
Match count: 46

Match[1][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251656"

Match[1][1]=3659174697251656

Match[2][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251652"

Match[2][1]=3659174697251652

Match[3][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251557"

Match[3][1]=3659174697251557

Match[4][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251648"

Match[4][1]=3659174697251648

Match[5][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251553"

Match[5][1]=3659174697251553

Match[6][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251644"

Match[6][1]=3659174697251644

Match[7][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251549"

Match[7][1]=3659174697251549

Match[8][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251545"

Match[8][1]=3659174697251545

Match[9][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251636"

Match[9][1]=3659174697251636

Match[10][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251632"

Match[10][1]=3659174697251632

Match[11][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251537"

Match[11][1]=3659174697251537

Match[12][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"**3659174697251659**"

Match[12][1]=3659174697251659

Match[13][0]=FullyMatched":{"readonly":true,"value":false}},"guid":"3659174697251655"

Please help me to handle this occurrence changing issues in response

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you're trying to extract a value from [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
2. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) therefore it's not the best idea to use regular expressions

Consider switching to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor), it provides much more powerful, robust, readable and reliable way to fetch the "interesting" data from JSON using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) language.

Going forward consider including the full response, it's not possible to guess how does it look like from what you posted.